# Facebook chatbot post callback doesn't have the correct data structure in nodejs

Tags: node.js, facebook-chatbot

I've implemented a webhook for a facebook chatbot with php using laravel and all works fine, when I message my bot I receive a post request with expected data structure and I manage to have all working well. Then I was trying to do the webhook implementation using nodejs but when I message my bot the post request that I receive is not the one it would be expected. This is kind of weird because I was able to validate the webhook with the token. I have used the same facebook app and page that I used for the php implementation so I don't think the problem is there. Here's the code in node: http://pastebin.com/0GQcXdV2

I would expect the request structure to be: http://pastebin.com/GFU89LjA

but instead it's this: http://pastebin.com/51S7DrkG

I'm sorry if this question seems stupid and I'm missing something obvious but can't figure out what. I'm kind of new to node js so maybe this is a newbie mistake, but if anyone can tell me what am I doing wrong it would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem by importing npm body-parser and make my express app use it for returning JSON. According to the npm documentation the bodyParser object provides middleware factories that expose the body of the request and assign it to `req.body` in plain text, json , raw or url encoding form body (https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser). To solve my problem i just added the following two lines of code:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

More information on body parser can be found [here](https://www.quora.com/What-exactly-does-body-parser-do-with-express-js-and-why-do-I-need-it).